# Can't seem to workout why my BlocProvider is failing

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, state-management, flutter-state

I am re writing Reso Coder's TDD clean architecture course with some minor changes. End goal is to have the exact same content with latest version of flutter with updated libraries & also to have the option of Riverpod state managment. But while using `flutter_bloc` I can't seem to make it work.

```
BlocProvider buildBody({required BuildContext context}){
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => sl<NumberTriviaBloc>(),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.5,
                  child: Placeholder()
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 50),
                  SizedBox(height: 25),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(child: Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30)),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Expanded(child: Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30),),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ) ;
  }
```

***the above code seems to work fine without any errors.***

But as soon as I introduce BlocBuilder (snippet given below), I get

`Error: Could not find the correct Provider<NumberTriviaBloc> above this BlocBuilder<NumberTriviaBloc, NumberTriviaState> Widget`

```
BlocProvider buildBody({required BuildContext context}){
    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => sl<NumberTriviaBloc>(),
      child: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              //start of the problem
              BlocBuilder<NumberTriviaBloc, NumberTriviaState>(
                  builder: (context, state) {
                    if (state is Empty) {
                      return Text("1");
                    }else{
                      return Text("2");
                    }
                  }
              ),
              //end of the problem
              Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/2.5,
                  child: Placeholder()
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0,),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 50),
                  SizedBox(height: 25),
                  Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(child: Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30)),
                      SizedBox(width: 10),
                      Expanded(child: Placeholder(fallbackHeight: 30),),
                    ],
                  )
                ],
              )

            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ) ;
  }
```

I have read everything I could get my hands on from the internet, still cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Full code available at [here](https://github.com/Sureya/resocoder-tdd-clean-course-flutter2.8.1/blob/main/lib/features/number_trivia/presentation/pages/number_trivia_page.dart) &
Dependecy injection logic available [here](https://github.com/Sureya/resocoder-tdd-clean-course-flutter2.8.1/blob/main/lib/injection_container.dart)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the bloc to `BlocBuilder` as well.

```
bloc: sl<NumberTriviaBloc>(),
```

Just add this to your `BlocBuilder` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your Center() widget with Builder() to get BlocProvider's context instead of context passed to buildBody method which doesn't have BlocProvider as parent.

```
return BlocProvider(
  create: (context) => sl<NumberTriviaBloc>(),
  child: Builder(
    builder: (context) => Center(...),//Wrap with Builder 
  ),
);
```